XCFramework via Cococpods dependent on other XCFramework pods causes crash
So I have a framework i need to distribute closed source so I created an XCFramework from it.
I have a parent framework, lets call it FrameworkA, it has a dependency of Framework B, Framework C, and Framework D.  Framework B also has a dependency on Framework C.  I created this chart to help illustrate:

Im using a dependency manager to link all of this and I need to add Cocoapods support (SPM is a separate issue) so this framework can be used by RN developers too, so I created some podspecs.
Example of how podspecs are structured
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "ParentFramework"
  s.version          = "1.0.0"
  s.summary          = "ParentFramework Summary"
  s.description      = "ParentFramework description"
  s.homepage         = "http://example.com/"
  s.license          = "Private"
  s.author           = { "Example" => "example@example.com" }
  s.source           = { :http => 'https://example.com/ParentFramework.xcframework.zip' }

  s.platform     = :ios, '16.4'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.swift_version = '5.0'

  s.dependency 'MyFrameworkB'
  s.dependency 'MyFrameworkC'

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'ParentFramework.xcframework'

end

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MyFrameworkB"
  s.version          = "1.0.0"
  s.summary          = "MyFrameworkB Summary"
  s.description      = "MyFrameworkB description"
  s.homepage         = "http://example.com/"
  s.license          = "Private"
  s.author           = { "Example" => "example@example.com" }
  s.source           = { :http => 'https://example.com/MyFrameworkB.xcframework.zip' }

  s.platform     = :ios, '16.4'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.swift_version = '5.0'

  s.dependency 'MyFrameworkC'

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFrameworkB.xcframework'

end

and MyFrameworkC would look like
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MyFrameworkC"
  s.version          = "1.0.0"
  s.summary          = "MyFrameworkC Summary"
  s.description      = "MyFrameworkC description"
  s.homepage         = "http://example.com/"
  s.license          = "Private"
  s.author           = { "Example" => "example@example.com" }
  s.source           = { :http => 'https://example.com/MyFrameworkC.xcframework.zip' }

  s.platform     = :ios, '16.4'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.swift_version = '5.0'

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFrameworkC.xcframework'

end

when i add MyFrameworkA to my podfile it will successfully retrieve MyFrameworkB and my project will compile and i can use public/open properties and methods from my frameworks. When i try to compile i get the following error:
dyld[99145]: Symbol not found: _$s14MyFrameworkBE16myFrameworkBMethod7request6resultyAD03AddhI7RequestC_ys6ResultOyAA15GenericResponseCs5Error_pGctF
  Referenced from: <1DA0CCF4-9E68-31D5-AEE0-F007A3D478B5> /Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F95AE061-9472-49BE-A4C4-CDD0513BDC1E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C1E7F412-2683-4F93-9625-FB1E86FF6470/TestApp.app/Frameworks/MyFrameworkB.framework/MyFrameworkB
  Expected in:     <57DF18F9-9F16-3DC5-B464-AAB4BFA5F0B0> /Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F95AE061-9472-49BE-A4C4-CDD0513BDC1E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C1E7F412-2683-4F93-9625-FB1E86FF6470/TestApp.app/Frameworks/MyFrameworkC.framework/MyFrameworkC

What am i missing to make this all work?
